# Audio streaming stop when screen gets Off in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am streaming mp3 on media-player, it plays continuos when your screen is on or you are doing multitasking but when you turn off screen it won't play audio continuously, it stucks many times.And I got this "info/warning (702,0) "on log cat

I tried     mp.setWakeMode(getBaseContext(),PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK);

I am using service to play audio streaming but still it stucks.

```
public class myPlayService extends Service{

MediaPlayer mp;
String link ="http://85.23.194.72:70/mp3/str";

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {


 mp = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mp.setDataSource(link);
        mp.setWakeMode(getBaseContext(),PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK);
        mp.prepareAsync();
        mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mp.start();
            }
        });

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}@Override public void onDestroy() { mp.stop();mp.release();}}
```

Comment: 702 means buffering end (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START) . I think connection has lost when screen off. Check it!

Comment: how can i persist the connection when screen gets off?

Comment: did you find any solution to solve this problem? @Waynecan you help us